# LazyInitializer vs Lazy<T> class. When to use each one

Tags: c#

What are the differences between [LazyInitializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazyinitializer.aspx) and [Lazy<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) classes? 
I know they both will initialize the object only on demand. 
When do I need to use each of them?

Comment: I see one benefit to using the `LazyInitializer`, you don't have to explicitly declare your object-to-be-initialized as `Lazy<T>`, you may keep it declared as itself.  That could be good if you cannot (for whatever reason) change the declaration to `Lazy<T>`.  So if you want lazy initialization on well-established code for an object, you don't need to change the declaration to use `Lazy<T>` as well as all the accesses to use the `Value` property, you can just call the `EnsureInitialized()` method at some point and you're set.

Comment: so you saying that LazyInitializer is better and there is no reason to use to Lazy class?

Comment: I probably won't be the best person to ask about this as I've never really used either before but from what I'm reading, use `LazyInitializer` if refactoring your code to support lazy initialization (using these classes) would be too expensive. If you know you want to support lazy initialization at the start, then use `Lazy<T>`. Any overheads using `Lazy<T>` is just an added cost and probably won't be too much of a factor.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Lazy<T>` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx)) is a generic wrapper which allows creating an instance of `T` on demand by holding a `T` factory method (`Func<T>`) and calling it when `Value` property getter is accessed.

`LazyInitializer` - static class with a set of static methods, this is just a helper which uses [Activator.CreateInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) (reflection) able to instantiate a given type instance. It does not keep any local private fields and does not expose any properties, so no memory usage overheads.

Worth noting that both classes uses `Func<T>` as instance factory.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazyinitializer.aspx) says in few words about `LazyInitializer` class:

> These routines avoid needing to allocate a dedicated,
> lazy-initialization instance, instead using references to ensure
> targets have been initialized as they are accessed.

PS:
I found interesting a way how `LazyIntiializer` checks whether instance already initialized, it just compare a passed in reference to a `default(T)`, nice:

```
private static T EnsureInitializedCore<T>(ref T target, Func<T> valueFactory) 
    where T : class
{
    T t = valueFactory();
    if (t == null)
    {
       throw new InvalidOperationException(Environment.GetResourceString("Lazy_StaticInit_InvalidOperation"));
    }

    Interlocked.CompareExchange<T>(ref target, t, default(T));
    return target;
}
```

What seems strange to me, it creates a new instance each time before an actual check:

```
T t = valueFactory(); 
// ... and only then does check
```

Comment: all of you say that both of them are the same and you say they act the same. So when I use what?!

Comment: @Stav Alfi: looks like my answer is not clear, basically I tried emphasize that `LazyInitializer()` does not require additional memory and uses reflection for instance factory, and `Lazy<T>` is just a wrapper class which hold on reference on the underlyiyng type `T` instance factory and instance itself when constructed, so if you need to pass over any class boundaries lazy-initialized instance - use wrapper `Lazy<T>` also if you are using lazy initialization for thousands instances - use `LazyInitializer` since it is not require additional memory, but slightly slower since need reflection call

Comment: From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y5814 - In multi-threaded scenarios, the first thread to invoke the initialization procedure is the one whose value is seen by all threads. Later threads also invoke the initialization procedure, but their results are not used. If this kind of potential race condition is not acceptable, use the overload of LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized that takes a Boolean argument and a synchronization object.

Comment: "it creates a new instance each time before an actual check": EnsureInitializedCore is called after target has already been checked for null, so a new instance is only created if target is null. There is a chance with multiple threads that valueFactory may be called multiple times, but Interlocked.CompareExchange ensures that target is set only once. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/LazyInitializer.cs,b1a70bb6e30b2c11

Answer (score 46):

I'm not sure if you're still looking into this, but I've had to delve into the details of both `Lazy<T>` and `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized<T>()` recently, so I thought I should share my findings.

First, some numbers.  I ran benchmarks using both methods on batches of ten million  values using both approaches, testing for memory use with `GC.GetTotalMemory(true)` and getting `Stopwatch` timings for instantiation, first value access, and subsequent value accesses:

```
Lazy<T> Memory Use:                  320,000,000 bytes (32B/instance)
EnsureInitialized<T>() Memory Use:   N/A

Lazy<T> Instantiation Time:          622.01 ms
EnsureInitialized<T>() Inst. Time:   N/A

Lazy<T> First Access:                1,373.50 ms
EnsureInitialized<T>() First Access: 72.94 ms

Lazy<T> Subsequent Accesses:         18.51 ms
EnsureInitialized<T>() Subsequent:   13.75 ms
```

(I used `LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly` with the `Lazy<T>'s`, which looks to be the same thread safety approach taken by `LazyInitializer` by default.)

As you can see, unless I've screwed up my tests somehow (never out of the question!), under these circumstances `LazyInitializer` is superior in just about every quantifiable way.  It has no memory or instantiation overhead, and it's faster both for creating and retrieving the value.

So, why would you want to use `Lazy<T>`?  Well, first, these were the test results on my x64 system, and it's possible you might get different results under other circumstances.

`Lazy<T>` can also result in clearer and more concise code.  `return myLazy.Value;` is a lot friendlier than `return LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref myValue, () => GetValue(foo));`

Additionally, `Lazy<T>` makes things a lot simpler if you're dealing with a value type, or with a reference type that could legitimately be `null`.  With `LazyInitializer`, you have to use a second boolean field to keep track of whether the value has been initialized, compounding the code clarity issue.  `Lazy<T>` is also simpler to use if you want stricter thread safety.

And in the grand scheme of things, most of the overhead is probably negligible for a lot of applications (although not always -- the reason I started looking into this is because I was working on an application involving millions of very small lazily-loaded values, and the 32-byte-per-instance overhead of `Lazy<T>` was actually starting to become inconvenient).

In the end, unless your application is very memory-intensive, I think it's usually going to be a matter of personal preference.  For non-null reference types, I personally think `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized<T>()` is a more elegant approach, but I can dig the code clarity argument too.

Comment: Been half a decade since your response and so things may have changed a little in regards to performance (hopefully for the better!) due to this https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/8963 (.net core only at the moment - i.e. not in current 4.7 .net framework).

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers say,

`Lazy<T>`

- Typically gives cleaner code: Just initialize with `x = new Lazy<T>(_ => new ...)` and use `x.Value` everywhere you access it.
- Allows different, predefined options for handling initialization and exceptions if multiple threads access the `Value` property of an uninitialized `Lazy<T>` object concurrently.

`LazyInitializer`

- Saves space and possibly also time: No need to initialize a new `Lazy<T>` object for every variable you declare.
- Allows you to delay providing initialization parameters until *use time*: `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref x, () => new X(initParameters))`

In conlusion, you only *need* to use `LazyInitializer` if space (and possibly time) is limited, or if you cannot specify all initialization parameters at declaration time.

*Personally* I prefer `Lazy<T>` whenever possible, because I find it gives cleaner code, and I don't have to handle initialization exceptions explicitly myself.

Comment: Doesn't initParameters adds an extra closure and factory method adds an extra delegate instance, which can be more excessive than Lazy<T>?

Answer (score 2):

`LazyInitializer` allows you the lazy initialization functionality without the overhead of creating a class for each lazily initialised object.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y5814) are the benefits `LazyInitializer` can provide.

It will be up to your own requirements as to whether the overhead created by using `Lazy<T>` is too much for the situation.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on Lazy Initializing explains it pretty clearly. See [**Lazy Initialization**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286.aspx). In short, `Lazy<T>` creates a new class (a constructed generic) for every `T` that you use, and a new instance of that class for every `T` instance you decalre -- *even if the underlying `T` is never initialized*. Using the *static* methods of `LazyIntializer` can be more complex for coding but avoids overhead of the `Lazy<T>` wrapper instances.

Answer (score 1):

I think this answered your question:
Another way of LazyInitialization System.Threading.ThreadLocal

**It is the same as Lazy, but the only difference is that it stores data on Thread Local basis. So the values on the each Thread would be a different copy of the Initialized object**.

more details from: http://www.cshandler.com/2011/09/different-ways-of-lazy-initialization.html

Answer (score -1):

```
`LazyInitializer`  of an object means its object creation is deferred until it is ued first.
```

An object of this form is created to improve performance and reduce memory wastage..

Whereas To Define a Lazy-initialized type we use `Lazy<T>`(generic Form) of `LazyInitializer` class

```
E.g:
 Lazy<Orders> _orders = new Lazy<Orders>();
```

For Further References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286.aspx